# Cut command with word as delimiter

Tags: command-line, text-processing, cut-command

Is there any cut command to cut based on a word
 eg :

```
171212 16082784       6264 XXX     xxxxxxxx Transaction XXXXX abend ABCD. The task has terminated abnormally because of a program check. 16:08:27
```

I want the output as :

```
171212 16082784       6264 XXX     xxxxxxxx Transaction XXXXX abend ABCD.
```

How to approach?

Comment: Which word do you mean?

Comment: ABCD is the word which i want to use as delimiter. And also, this is a log, and like ABCD, i am having someother keywords too. I want an approach in general

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257514/how-to-delete-everything-after-a-certain-pattern-or-a-string-in-a-file

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I suggest:

```
awk -F 'ABCD' '{print $1 FS "."}' file
```

Output:

```
171212 16082784       6264 XXX     xxxxxxxx Transaction XXXXX abend ABCD.
```

`FS` contains your delimiter "ABCD". "ABCD" is a regex.

Comment: +1 for the solution. I wanted to get the sentence after the word so, I did    '' awk -F 'ABCD' '{print $2 FS }' file ''   ;  so I got "The task has terminated abnormally because of a program check. 16:08:27"  ;  Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 7):

`sed` version:

```
sed 's/ABCD.*/ABCD./' input.txt
171212 16082784       6264 XXX     xxxxxxxx Transaction XXXXX abend ABCD.
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257514/how-to-delete-everything-after-a-certain-pattern-or-a-string-in-a-file

Comment: I've changed it, but would it make a difference?

Comment: It would still work - just pointing out it's not necessary

Answer (score 6):

`awk` can do the job if you provide `-F` flag with the word which you want to use:

```
$ awk -F 'test'  '{print $1;print $2}'  <<<  "onetesttwotest"                                                            
one
two
```

In your particular case, that would be:

```
$ awk -F 'ABCD' '{print $1,FS}' input.txt                                                                                
171212 16082784       6264 XXX     xxxxxxxx Transaction XXXXX abend  ABCD
```

Judging from your example, you're only trying to print stuff up to `ABCD` so deleting everything after that is also an option:

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,0,match($0,/ABCD/)+4);}' input.txt                                                               
171212 16082784       6264 XXX     xxxxxxxx Transaction XXXXX abend ABCD.
```

Comment: They also want to keep the 'ABCD.'

Comment: Yea..ABCD must be there

Comment: I suggest `awk '{print gensub(/(.*ABCD\.).*/,"\\1",1)}'`.

Answer (score 3):

`grep` solution:

```
grep -o '^.*ABCD\.' input.txt
```

The regular expression will match to each line that begin `^` with any character `.` repeated number of times `*` and ends with the string `ABCD.` The backslash `\` escapes the special meaning of the dot `.` at the end.

The option `-o` will tell the `grep` command to print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line.

Answer (score 3):

`cut` can itself perform this job. Not based on a word, but based on `.` delimiter.

Use :

```
cut -f 1 -d '.' input.txt | xargs -I "%" echo %.
```

**Output**

```
rooney@bond-pc:~$ cat input.txt 
171212 16082784       6264 XXX     xxxxxxxx Transaction XXXXX abend ABCD. The task has terminated abnormally because of a program check. 16:08:27
rooney@bond-pc:~$ 
rooney@bond-pc:~$ cut -f 1 -d '.' input.txt | xargs -I "%" echo %.
171212 16082784       6264 XXX     xxxxxxxx Transaction XXXXX abend ABCD.
```

`xargs` is used here only to append `.` at the end of string `ABCD`.